# When will SE be down?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, date

#### [SE will be down/read only <s>today</s> 2017-05-04 at 00:00 UTC until 00:20 UTC.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295285/338745)

Your challenge is to output a truthy value if SE is down/read only and a falsy value if SE is not. You may not have any input, and you must use date builtins to determine if SE is down/read only (no actually querying the SE api!) Example output:

```
12:34 UTC 03 May 2017 -> false

00:00 UTC 04 May 2017 -> true

00:20 UTC 20 May 2017 -> undefined, see below
```

That's undefined behavior, because it's too far after the window of time. 
 To be clear, you can assume your program will be run from UTC `8:00` today (5/3/17) to UTC `1:00` tomorrow (5/4/17).

```
00:21 UTC 04 May 2017 -> false

00:20 UTC 04 May 2017 -> true

00:10 UTC 04 May 2017 -> true
```

Note that any truthy or falsy values are allowed, not just `true` and `false`. You must be accurate to the nearest second, and no changing the system clock! You may assume that your program is being run on a machine on the `+0 UTC` time zone.

Comment: `sudo time <insert time here>
&& echo true`

Comment: @Okx no changing the time!

Comment: I'd suggest updating the test cases to use a universal date format rather than American.

Comment: Why do I have twice as many answers as upvotes?

Comment: @programmer5000 Not everyone upvotes when answering. Sometimes I answer a question but don't upvote it because it wasn't that interesting. I wouldn't downvote unless it was actually a bad challenge. (By the way, I upvoted, but I might not be answering. :P)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *You must be accurate to the nearest minute*. Should we round the time somehow? Do we have to look at the seconds at all? What should be displayed at `00:20:01`?

Comment: Step #1, trigger bot army to DDoS SE, Step #2, return "1"

Comment: First, as the SO SRE Manager, I want to say that I love this question.  Good work!  However, I do want to remind people that the site won't be hard down... just in read-only mode.  That said, I will be selecting on answer to this question to help me determine when to start the procedure.

Comment: @TomOnTime Thanks! And is that more clear?

Comment: @programmer5000 That is better. Thanks. (I actually didn't expect you to change anything, but thanks for the edit!) Much appreciated!

Comment: @programmer5000 Could you please answer Dennis question above?

Comment: @Dennis you must be accurate to the nearest second. For example, `00:20:01` should be falsey.

Comment: That would mean your own answer is invalid, no? So would many other answers; neither your original revision nor the current test cases mention seconds.

Comment: [Relevant chat conversation.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37622561#37622561)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>32</s> <s>26</s> <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
žažb«21‹
```

Explanation:

```
ža          Is the current hour &
  žb        current minute
     «      concatenated
        ‹   less than
      21    twenty one?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X@LRfUmHVhsZPmrY@f//17x83eTE5IxUAA)

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>26</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) and 1 byte thanks to [Luke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63774/luke).

```
_=>new Date/12e5%72<1
```

Checks if time passed in current day is less than 1200000ms (1200s or 20min). Assumes downtime to be 20 minutes not 21, which appears to be the case in the linked post. `00:20UTC` is the exclusive upper bound.

Comment: Save 2 bytes by using `new Date` instead of `new Date()`.

Comment: `<2` to save another byte.

Comment: You don't need the `+`; `/` automatically converts `new Date` to a `Number`.

Comment: Is the function declaration (_=>) needed?  JavaScript can run globally.

Comment: @Brilliand Yes, otherwise output would be needed, the shortest being `alert` which is a lot longer

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)

```python
import time
print time.time()/1200%72<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXohAfn5lbkF9UEh@voVSSmZuqpKkHojQ09Q2NDAxUzY1sDP//BwA)

Uses the same algorithm as my JS and Charcoal answers.

Comment: Is `/72<1` different from `<72`?

Comment: @xnor whoops sorry copied it wrong, fixed now

Comment: No, I mean that I think `print time.time()/1200<72` would be a shorter way to express the same thing.

Comment: @xnor I'm pretty sure that only works on the first day of the epoch though

Comment: Oops, I meant `%1200/72<1` -> `%1200<72`. Your TIO links to the `%1200/72<1` version -- is that a mistake?

Comment: @xnor Yeah, sorry

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
6ŒT|0Ḍ<21
```

Requires `TZ` to be set to `UTC`, which is the case for TIO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@292dFJIjcHDHT02Rob//3/Ny9dNTkzOSAUA)

#### How it works

```
6ŒT|0Ḍ<21  Main link. No arguments.

6ŒT        Get the current time as a string, in the format HH:MM.
   |0      Bitwise OR each character with 0. This casts the characters to int and
           maps the non-digit character : to 0.
     Ḍ     Undecimal; convert from base 10 to integer.
      <21  Compare the result with 21, so 00:00 to 00:20 return 1, all others
           return 0.
```

Comment: (Everyone was) Outgolfed by Dennis! Nice job!

Comment: [Not everyone...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118642/12012)

Comment: If the downtime latest 'til `00:21`, I could save a byte...

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>32</s> 11 bytes

```
K/12e5%72<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@@tb2iUaqpqbmRj@P//17x83eTE5IxUAA)

Answer (score 3):

## JS (ES6), <s>52</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
y=>(x=new Date).getUTCMinutes()<21&&!x.getUTCHours()
```

Why is `Date` so long? Just gets the minutes past `00:00` and returns `true` if they are < 21, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Save 2 bytes by using `new Date` instead of  `new Date()`.

Comment: -1 this doesn't check the date

Comment: @ASCII-only the question says it dosen't have to.

Comment: Save another byte with `y=>(x=new Date).getUTCMinutes()<21&&!x.getUTCHours()`.

Comment: @Shaggy thanks again! My golfing isn't great.

Comment: Save another 6 bytes by using local time instead of UTC - the question says you may assume local time *is* UTC.

Answer (score 3):

### zsh, <strike>38</strike> 37 bytes:

```
date +%H\ %M|read h m;((h==0&&m<21))
```

Answer (score 3):

### bash, 40 bytes:

```
read h m< <(date +%H\ %M);((h==0&&m<21))
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL (Dyalog), 14 bytes

```
∧/1 20>2↑3↓⎕TS
```

`∧/` is it all-true (AND reduction) that

`1 20>` these numbers are greater than

`2↑` the first two elements of

`3↓⎕TS` the current **T**ime **S**tamp with three elements dropped

Comment: What character is the `⎕`?

Comment: @programmer5000 `⎕` (Quad) is a prefix for system names in APL. It *is* supposed to be an empty rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 (NON-REPL) + time, <s>81</s> 77 bytes

<sup>-4 bytes thanks to Bahrom</sup>

```python
import time;e=str(time.strftime('%H:%M'));print(e[:2]=='00'and int(e[3:])<21)
```

A naïve approach, turning the current date to string and analysing its characters.

Comment: You can save a whole bunch of bytes by using a different format string, and if you're using the shell, you don't need the print function: `import time;e=str(time.strftime('%H:%M'));e[:2]=='00'and int(e[2:])<21`. This can probably be golfed even further too.

Comment: (pretty new to golfing and the rules) but in the shell this also seems to output the correct results: `import time;time.localtime();_.tm_hour==0 and _.tm_min<21`. We're not beating ASCII-only anyway lol

Comment: Ok, I cannot edit now, maybe later

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
‹﹪÷ＵＰtime.time⟦⟧¹²⁰⁰¦⁷²¦¹
```

Prints `-` for truthy, nothing for falsy.

### Explanation

```
    ＵＰtime.time⟦⟧          Python function time.time()
   ÷               ¹²⁰⁰      Divided by 1200
 ﹪                    ¦⁷²   Modulo 72
‹                         ¦¹ Less than 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/@oYef7nasOb3@/Z@v7PRtKMnNT9UDEo/nLHs1ffmjnoU2PGjcA0aFljxq3H9p0aNmhnf//AwA)

Comment: What does the `⟦⟧` do here? Do you need a list or arrowlist literal?

Comment: Yeah, a list is required here, but now that I think about it I should make it optional

Comment: Oh, so it's a list of arguments? Yeah, you should make it optional, calling the function without arguments by default.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Done

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

*Thanks to Dennis for several corrections*

```
Z'1\480*7<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@lbhhjYmGgZW7z/z8A)

#### Explanation

```
Z'    % Push current date and time as a float. Integer part is day, decimal part is time
1\    % Modulo 1. This gives the time, in units of one day
480*  % Multiply by 480
7<    % Less than 7? Note that 21 minutes / one day equals 7 / 480. Implicitly display.
```

Comment: Should that be `l72` rather than `171` in your explanation?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, thanks for catching that!

Comment: It's still `72` vs `71`. Also wouldn't this return `0` at `00:20`?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, this would return `0` at `00:20`, but would return `1` at `00:20` minus a small fraction of a second (given by the machine epsilon for `double` data type times `86400`). The challenge says "you must be accurate to the nearest minute", so I understand it's acceptable

Comment: That's probably what the post on Mother Meta meant, but the challenge has `00:20 -> true` as a test case. Left a comment on the question.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I hadn't seen that test case. I've corrected to use `00:21` as threshold.

Comment: Hm, looking at the other answers, it seems like most interpreted the challenge the same way you did. Let's hope the OP clarifies soon.

Comment: @Dennis Or, if "accurate to the nearest minute" means 30-second precision I could save 1 byte with current interpretation using 1/70 or 1/71 as threshold; let's wait for clarification

Answer (score 2):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 17 bytes

```
/o
\T@/4&;'-.C+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@fzxUT4qBvomatLqqr56yd9/8/AA)

Assumes to be run on a machine whose timezone is set to UTC (like the TIO server).

#### Explanation

While in Ordinal mode, the IP bounces diagonally up and down through the program. While in Cardinal mode, the IP wraps around the edges like most other Fungeoids.

```
/   Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal.
T   Push a string representing the current date and time, in the format:
    YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmm±AA:BB
/   Reflect to E. Switch to Cardinal.
4&  Run the next command 4 times.
;   Discard four elements from the top of the stack. Since we're in Cardinal mode,
    this attempts to discard four integers. But the top stack value is a string so
    it gets implicitly converted to all the integers contained in the string. So
    year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds, timezone hour,
    timezone minute will be pushed separately. Then the last four of these
    will be discarded, so that we end up with the minute and the hour on
    top of the stack.
'  Push 21.
-   Subtract it from the minutes. Gives something negative for minutes 0 to 20.
.C  Compute the binomial coefficient n-choose-n. This gives 0 for negative
    results and 1 for non-negative ones. SE is down if both this value and
    the current hour are zero.
+   Add the two values. Iff they are both zero, we still get a zero.
n   Logical NOT of the value. Turns 0 into 1 and everything else into 0.
\   Reflect to NE. Switch to Ordinal.
o   Implicitly convert the result to a string and print it.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
&g20.d7!.d6
```

[Online interpreter link](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26g20.d7%21.d6&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>55</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

*-1 byte from @robbie0630's comment.*

```bash
a=`date +%s`;echo $[1493856000<a&a<1493857200?1:0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@59om5CSWJKqoK1anGCdmpyRr6ASbWhiaWxhamZgYGCTqJZoA@GaGxkY2BtaGcT@/w8A)

The advantage of this solution is that it works for any date (so will return `1` only for the period defined in the challenge, as it uses epoch time).

Comment: Shave off a byte by replacing `$(...)` with `\`...\``

Answer (score 0):

## Swift + Foundation, 178 bytes

```
import Foundation;var d=String(describing:Date());func g(_ s:Int)->String{return String(d[d.index(d.startIndex,offsetBy:s)])};print(g(11)+g(12)=="00" ?Int(g(14)+g(15))!<21:false)
```

Quite short by swift standards. **[Check it out!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5909c110ef829376a284faab)**

As in my Python answer, I basically converted the current `Date` to a string and have analysed its digits, depending on which I printed the bool.

Answer (score 0):

### R, 65 bytes

```
library(lubridate)
x=Sys.time()
print(all(!hour(x)&minute(x)<21))
```

Checks if the hour == 0 and the minute < 21.

Answer (score 0):

## PostgreSQL, 43 characters

```sql
select now()between'170503'and'170503 0:20'
```

Just because I prefer SQL for date/time calculations.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ psql -c "select now()between'170503'and'170503 0:20'"
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```